# How to fetch an soapui xml in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, soap, soapui

I get an api ,when i fetch it on postman it getting response of an xml result.How to fetch that in my react code.The documentation says that it is soap version 2.0 and soapui doesn,t work correctly with our WSDL

I want to know how to fetch that data in my react app

Comment: Can you share WSDL 2.0 URL?